# Нужно написать функцию которая удаляет все гласные из строки

Tags: javascript

Я не знаю как сравнить все символы с каждым элементом массива гласных. Я попытался решить это но ничего не получилось.
Вот весь код:

```
function disemvowel(str) {
  var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y'];
  str = for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == for(var j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++)  {
      var letter = vowels[j];
} ) {
      str[i] = str[i + 1]; 
    }
  } else {
      str[i] = str[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Проще всего использовать метод [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) и [регулярное выражение](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript).

```js
let disemvowel = (str) => str.replace(/[aeiouy]/gi, '')

console.log(disemvowel('testaeiouyAEIOUYtest'));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не думал, что можно обойтись всего лишь двумя строками

Comment: Можно чуть короче: `str.replace(/[aeiouy]/gi, '')`

Comment: @Yaant, спасибо, поправил ответ.